# Confirming an email on a e-commerce site, complete strategy

Tags: users, email, confirmation, flow

We are designing a e-commerce site, that requires email verification to create an account.
The account is useful only for

- the check out (where name, phone, email are needed) and  viewing the
- Favorites listings, living in "My Account" (email for account log in
  is needed).

User can register a new account when he/ she...

1. is checking out,
2. will be asked for it, when "favorites/ likes" an item,
3. on his/ her own will. through the header link.

The Strategy is than at sign-up, we ask for an email and password and send him/ her a verification link.

When the link is pressed, the user will be guided to "my Account" profile page to fill the rest of  the personal data.

We cannot control when the verification will occur, and we certainly do not want to stop the user, browsing our site, till he/ she confirms the email, -unless it is the check out process, where the personal data are required.

**Here are the questions:**

1. After informing about the email verification processes (*Please, check your inbox!*) and till the user confirms it, while he/ she is browsing in our site (maybe deciding whether he/ she will proceed to check out, or likes our prices, so to complete the registration), should we create a temp account (saving but not showing the Favorites, and sho and if the user proceeds to check out, or going to "myAccount" we will ask again for verification? -or just wait for the user to confirm his/ her email?
2. If the user does not confirm that time its email, the next time, shall we treat him/ her as an old user with no registered account (eg. when trying to log in, we re-send him an email and remind him to verify <> When trying to sign up, we inform that this email is being used) ? <> or just forget about him/her and next time make him re-register from scratch?
3. When registering while he / she is checking out, shall we have a different flow, since name and phone becomes mandatory, so filling the rest of info on my account may create many problems?

Thanks

Comment: Does the verification link sent by email have an expiration date? When the user initiates account creation how are you keeping track of their use on site between initial account creation and completing verification? IP address?

Comment: What is the context of Q#3? Is this a user that initiated account creation but did not yet verify? And has not completed the rest of the account information?

Comment: 1. The verification link should have an expiration date for safety reasons and maintenance.
2. I guess cookies and IP address. -Don't know yet really. Does it matter?
3. In 3, user might have no account initially, or an unverified account. Never the less. in both cases he will be called, at some point, to go to his inbox to click the verification email and redirected to complete his/ her data somewhere -that we would love to be the profile page, and then continue straight to check out.

Thank U